# Почему при повторном использовании функции, часть её кода пропускается?

Tags: python, функции, разработка-игр

Функция нужная для игры "X и O" выглядит так:

```
player1_marker=''
player2_marker=''
def game_on():
        board = ['#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
        player1_marker, player2_marker = choose_first()
        if random.randint(1,2) == 1:
            while not full_board_check(board):
                display_board(board)
                print('Player 1 playing')
                position = player_choice(board)
                place_marker(board, player1_marker, position)
                if win_check(board, player1_marker):
                    display_board(board)
                    print('Player 1 won')
                    board = ['#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
                    replay()
                if full_board_check(board):
                    display_board(board)
                    print('It is a tie!')
                    board = ['#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
                    replay()
                display_board(board)
                print('Player 2 playing')
                position = player_choice(board)
                place_marker(board, player2_marker, position)
                if win_check(board, player2_marker):
                    display_board(board)
                    print('Player 2 won')
                    board = ['#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
                    replay()
        if random.randint(1,2) == 2:
            while not full_board_check(board):
                display_board(board)
                print('Player 2 playing')
                position = player_choice(board)
                place_marker(board, player2_marker, position)
                if win_check(board, player2_marker):
                    display_board(board)
                    print('Player 2 won')
                    board = ['#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
                    replay()
                if full_board_check(board):
                    display_board(board)
                    print('It is a tie!')
                    board = ['#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
                    replay()
                display_board(board)
                print('Player 1 playing')
                position = player_choice(board)
                place_marker(board, player1_marker, position)
                if win_check(board, player1_marker):
                    display_board(board)
                    print('Player 1 won')
                    board = ['#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
                    replay()

    
if replay():
    game_on()
else:
    print('Goodbye!')
```

Когда я вписываю, что хочу играть заново функция не запрашивает выбор: Х или О. За это отвечает функция player_input(), которая находится в choose_first():

```
def choose_first():
    random.randint(1, 2)
    if random.randint(1,2) == 1:
        print('Player 1 is first to play')
        player1_marker, player2_marker = player1_input()
        return player1_marker, player2_marker
        
    elif random.randint(1,2) == 2:
        print('Player 2 is first to play')
        player1_marker, player2_marker = player2_input()
        return player1_marker, player2_marker
```

Функция, позволяющая выбрать Х или О для игрока, который ходит первым:

```
def player1_input():
    global player1_marker
    global player2_marker
    while player1_marker !='X' and player1_marker !='O':
        player1_marker=input('Player 1, choose X or O: ')
    if player1_marker=='X':
        player2_marker='O'
    else:
        player2_marker='X'
    return player1_marker, player2_marker
```

Вместо этого функция сразу переходит на условия `if random.randint(1,2) ==`

Answer (score 2):

`random.randint(1,2)` при каждом вызове дает случайный результат (это был бы странный генератор случайных чисел, если бы он при каждом запросе выдавал только один вариант из двух). При первой проверке может дать результат 2, во второй проверке - 1, в итоге у вас ни одна ветка `if` не выполнится. Нужно результат первого вызова записать в переменную, потом значение этой переменной проверять в `if` (у вас первый `random.randint(1, 2)` вообще выполняется "в пустую" - результат никак не учитывается):

```
def choose_first():
    r = random.randint(1, 2)
    if r == 1:
        print('Player 1 is first to play')
        player1_marker, player2_marker = player1_input()
        return player1_marker, player2_marker
        
    elif r == 2:
        print('Player 2 is first to play')
        player1_marker, player2_marker = player2_input()
        return player1_marker, player2_marker
```

Т.к. вариантов всего два, то можно второй `elif` заменить на `else`, а `randint` внести обратно в `if` - вызов `randint` всего один, если он вернет 1, то выполнится первая ветка, если что-то другое, то ветка `else`:

```
def choose_first():
    if random.randint(1, 2) == 1:
        print('Player 1 is first to play')
        player1_marker, player2_marker = player1_input()
        return player1_marker, player2_marker
    else:
        print('Player 2 is first to play')
        player1_marker, player2_marker = player2_input()
        return player1_marker, player2_marker
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас player1_marker сохраняется в global

```
global player1_marker
global player2_marker
```

и при переиспользовании условие на while сразу False